# remote mysql inseting tables in loop very slow

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress

im trying to insert lots of items from a text file in a loop. the loop is obviously its a while loop sending a command for sendtodb every line of a text file. Using a local db this is very fast (1.9 million insets took around 4 hours) but when doing this on a remote mysql server on hosting its like 1 inset per second which would take days or weeks! any ideas please?

```
    private void sendtodb(string image, string title, string content, int cat)
    {
        string cs = @"the connection string";
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();
        try
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt,post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent, guid,menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count) "
                + "VALUES (@post_author, @post_date, @post_date_gmt, @post_content, @post_title, @post_excerpt,@post_status,@comment_status,@ping_status,@post_password,@post_name,@to_ping,@pinged,@post_modified,@post_modified_gmt,@post_content_filtered,@post_parent, @guid, @menu_order, @post_type, @post_mime_type, @comment_count)";

            //  cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_author", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_date_gmt", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_content", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = content;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_title", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_excerpt", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "publish";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@comment_status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "open";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ping_status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "open";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@to_ping", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pinged", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = "";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_modified", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_modified_gmt", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_content_filtered", MySqlDbType.LongText).Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_parent", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@guid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@menu_order", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "post";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_mime_type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@comment_count", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from wp_posts order by ID desc LIMIT 1";
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int idcolumn = 0;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                idcolumn = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["ID"]);
            }
            dataReader.Close();

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)" + "VALUES (@post_id,@meta_key,@meta_value)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@post_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = idcolumn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@meta_key", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Image";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@meta_value", MySqlDbType.LongText).Value = image;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order)" + "VALUES (@object_id,@term_taxonomy_id,@term_order)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@object_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = idcolumn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@term_taxonomy_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cat;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@term_order", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            textBox4.Text = idcolumn.ToString();

            textBox2.Text = "MySQL version : " + conn.ServerVersion;

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            textBox2.Text = ex.ToString();

        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is for a massive wordpress database

Comment: Removed `PHP` tag. It's got nothing to do with this.

Comment: Is insertion done from local to remote or locally remote? Also consider using `TRANSACTIONS`. Might help. Not to mention, hope you don't connect on each push... I really hope you don't and the code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect to the DB outside of your code. Right now you're doing one-connection-per-insert, which is ludicrously inefficient.

The steps should be:

```
connection to database
while(have data) {
    use connection to insert data
}
disconnect from database
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try inserting multiple rows in one mysql request?

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

Comment: Just be mindful of exceeding the **[Max Packet Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)**. Also, sending one giant string like this over the network can be prone to errors at the network level. Ever have a 1GB file download from the internet finish and be corrupted? Not fun

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a server side code to insert queries you are wasting too much time on connections, sending data back and forth, you need a local, sql-side solution.

Just create an sql file filled with queries you need to insert seperated by `;` and load it on mysql server using `SOURCE` syntax documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html). This will ensure the fastest way possible to insert those rows, since you don't waste any of your precious times on server side code.